# SQLAlchemy update iteration (performace)

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

```
a=[1,2]
ids = [id1, id2]

all_rows = Table.query.filter(Table.id.in_(ids)).update({Table.price: ...}
```

I am trying to speed up update of my records in db, first I pick up those records I want to update by list of updates and then I would like to update price of record by list a in sense that both those list are sorted and 1 should be for id1, 2 for id2.

Is it possible to do that and if so how?

I know there is an option to do it one by one in for loop but... that is not really fast if running over bigger amount of records.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this kind of update by using a [case expression](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case) for the update values.

For example, if you wanted to set the values of `col2`depending on the values of `col1`, for a particular group of ids, you could do this:

```py
ids = [1, 2, 3]
targets = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # col1
values = [10, 20, 30]  # col2

case = db.case(*((Table.col1 == t, v) for t, v in zip(targets, values)))
Table.query.filter(Table.id.in_(ids)).update({'col2': case})
```